# change a value in a specific location in a text file in python

Tags: python

Is there a library/command in python to change a value in a specific location in a text file?

E.g. lets say I have a file called test.txt containing following data:

```
abc 123.2  45 text_data
ghk 12.43  123.45  89.3
```

The key thing is that this text file cannot be read as a structured data e.g. by using pandas or assuming that regular columns exist.

So, I have a separate file where I specify the row and columns which need to be changed to a new value.

```
row column_start  column_end new_value
2    5             9            10.4
```

Should replace 12.43 in the 2nd row with 10.4 in test.txt

Comment: If you can't assume any structure to the data, how do you have rows and columns. Are they just character positions?

Comment: Hi Jonah, that's right. those are character positions. thanks for clarifying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the line, extract the row, start,end and val then you can use [fileinput.input](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.input) to change the original file:

```
from fileinput import input
from sys import stdout

line = "2    5             9            10.4"

r, st, ed, val = line.split()
r, st, ed = int(r), int(st), int(ed)
for ind, line in enumerate(input("test.txt",inplace=True), 1):
    if ind == r:
        stdout.write(line.replace(line[st-1:ed], val))
    else:
        stdout.write(line)
```

That could replace more than just the value you want so slicing may be the safest approach:

```
for ind, line in enumerate(input("test.txt", inplace=True), 1):
    if ind == r:
        new = line[:st-1] + val + line[ed:]
        stdout.write(new)
    else:
        stdout.write(line)
```

If you have multiple lines to change use a dict to create mappings:

```
from fileinput import input
from sys import stdout

with open("changes.txt") as f:
    next(f)
    data = {int(r): {"st": int(st), "ed": int(ed), "val": val} for r, st, ed, val in map(str.split, f)}
    for ind, line in enumerate(input("test.txt"), 1):
        if ind in data:
            d = data[ind]
            new = line[:d["st"] - 1] + d["val"] + line[d["ed"]:]
            stdout.write(new)
        else:
            stdout.write(line)
```

Comment: No worries,you're welcome.  you could also write to a tempfile using shutil to overwrite the original, it is covered in the last part of this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/32801382/2141635

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
import sys
# load the values from the instruction file however you want (a separate problem)
row=2
column_start=5
column_end=9
new_value=10.4

# process the data
for line_num, contents in enumerate(open("test.txt")):
    if line_num == row - 1:
        contents = contents[:column_start-1] + str(new_value) + contents[column_end:]
    # write the results somewhere
    sys.stdout.write(contents)
```